# persisting non persisted objects using jpa/hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity called Order, which has an attribute that is a List of LineItem objects. When I persist an order, I would like the line item objects it contains to be persisted as well. How can I do this? I tried to set the cascadeType for the List to a cascade type of ALL, but that causes a constraint violation. I tried to then use MERGE, but that didn't add anything to the LineItem table. Any ideas?

```
public class Order {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private List<LineItem> orderSegments;
    ...
}

public class LineItem {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID")
    private Order order;
    ...    
}
```

When I persist an Order, for some reason, nothing gets put into the line item table

Comment: Could you share how you have done relationship mapping for Order and LineItem ?

Comment: You do need to use a cascade, what was the specific constraint violation that you received?

Comment: Well, I just re-ran my unit tests, and there is no violation, but it doesn't put anything in the line item table. I definitely am adding 2 line items to the order, then persisting the order.

Comment: Firstly, you need to add a Cascade option to the @OneToMany. Secondly you need to ensure both sides of the relationship are set. See here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23648953/1356423. That will fix your issue.