# Spring Data Jpa - Self many to many with additional column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to do a self ManyToMany relationship in Spring Data Jpa,

Terminal.class

```
package com.sopiyan.travel.model.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created by Sopiyan on 31/05/2016.
 */
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "terminal")
//@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idTerminal")
public class Terminal implements Serializable, Comparable<Terminal> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_terminal", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String idTerminal;
    @Column(name = "nama_terminal", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String namaTerminal;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_kota",referencedColumnName = "id_kota", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Kota kota;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "terminalAsal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlTransient
    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection<Rute> listTerminalAsal;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "terminalTujuan", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlTransient
    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection<Rute> listTerminalTujuan;

    public Collection<Rute> getListTerminalAsal() {
        return listTerminalAsal;
    }

    public void setListTerminalAsal(Collection<Rute> listTerminalAsal) {
        this.listTerminalAsal = listTerminalAsal;
    }

    public Collection<Rute> getListTerminalTujuan() {
        return listTerminalTujuan;
    }

    public void setListTerminalTujuan(Collection<Rute> listTerminalTujuan) {
        this.listTerminalTujuan = listTerminalTujuan;
    }

    public Kota getKota() {
        return kota;
    }

    public void setKota(Kota kota) {
        this.kota = kota;
    }

    public String getIdTerminal() {
        return idTerminal;
    }

    public void setIdTerminal(String idTerminal) {
        this.idTerminal = idTerminal;
    }

    public String getNamaTerminal() {
        return namaTerminal;
    }

    public void setNamaTerminal(String namaTerminal) {
        this.namaTerminal = namaTerminal;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Terminal terminal) {
        return this.idTerminal.compareTo(terminal.getIdTerminal());
    }
}
```

Rute.class

```
package com.sopiyan.travel.model.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created by Sopiyan on 31/05/2016.
 */
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "rute")
public class Rute implements Serializable, Comparable<Rute>{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_rute", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String idRute;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_terminal_asal", referencedColumnName = "id_terminal")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Terminal terminalAsal;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_terminal_tujuan", referencedColumnName = "id_terminal")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Terminal terminalTujuan;
    @Column(name = "harga", nullable = false)
    private double harga;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rute")
    @XmlTransient
    private Collection<Tiket> listTiket;

    public Collection<Tiket> getListTiket() {
        return listTiket;
    }

    public void setListTiket(Collection<Tiket> listTiket) {
        this.listTiket = listTiket;
    }

    public String getIdRute() {
        return idRute;
    }

    public void setIdRute(String idRute) {
        this.idRute = idRute;
    }

    public Terminal getTerminalAsal() {
        return terminalAsal;
    }

    public void setTerminalAsal(Terminal terminalAsal) {
        this.terminalAsal = terminalAsal;
    }

    public Terminal getTerminalTujuan() {
        return terminalTujuan;
    }

    public void setTerminalTujuan(Terminal terminalTujuan) {
        this.terminalTujuan = terminalTujuan;
    }

    public double getHarga() {
        return harga;
    }

    public void setHarga(double harga) {
        this.harga = harga;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rute rute) {
        return this.idRute.compareTo(rute.getIdRute());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to save Rute Entity, but I'm getting errors. Where is the problem?

Error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.sopiyan.travel.model.entity.Terminal; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.sopiyan.travel.model.entity.Terminal

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:299)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.sopiyan.travel.UserTest.simpan(UserTest.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.sopiyan.travel.model.entity.Terminal
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:768)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:761)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:751)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:506)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Could you past code for saving Rute entity?

Comment: Rute rute = new Rute();
Terminal asal = terminalService.cariBerdasarkanId("2e35668f-c22b-4169-8174-4072a048f50c");
Terminal tujuan = terminalService.cariBerdasarkanId("4928b4da-e63e-42d7-b6eb-ddf63d9b321b");
rute.setHarga(new Double("65000"));
asal.getListTerminalAsal().add(rute);
tujuan.getListTerminalTujuan().add(rute);
rute.setTerminalAsal(asal);
rute.setTerminalTujuan(tujuan);
ruteRepository.save(rute); @Constantine

Comment: this might help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645091/spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-on-manytomany-re