# Annotation @GeneratedValue caused InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have two classes connected with many-to-many relationship:

*Book.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "release_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date releaseDate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "cover_image")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private UploadFile coverImage;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private UploadFile content;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "book_category", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Category> categories;
}
```

*Category.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // I also tried an option with adding cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    private List<Book> books;
}
```

When I want to add book to database I recive following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.github.model.Category; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.github.model.Category
```

Interestingly removing @GeneratedValue annotation from the Category class causes everything to work as well as possible. To add book I extends JpaRepository:

```
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>{
}
```

and then

```
Repository repository;
repository.save(book);
```

What's also should be important I'm using **h2** database. To see all the code you can visit my github: https://github.com/mmaciula/Library/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github

**EDIT**

After I added @Column annotations the problem with `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` was solved. However, the problem with mapping collection appears. Here is the stack track I receive:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection com.github.model.Book.categories
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection com.github.model.Book.categories
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find column with logical name: id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(book) and its related supertables and secondary tables
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(book) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

**EDIT 2**

When I changed `referencedColumnName` in @JoinTable from id to book_id I recived DataIntegrityViolationException shown below:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKAM8LLDERP40MVBBWCEQPU6L2S: PUBLIC.BOOK_CATEGORY FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CATEGORY(CATEGORY_ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
insert into book_category (book_id, category_id) values (?, ?) [23506-196]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: seems like you just need to add CascadeType.ALL as the cascade type for that relationship. That should make it work

      @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascadeType=CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: @GSUgambit I tried to add `CascadeType.ALL` but still got an exception.

Comment: maybe you should add the cascade type to the category side. The root of your problem is that the category is not persisted so it cannot save the book to a "detached" [unsaved / managed by hibernate] category. Typically casecade type solves this. Sorry I'm a bit sleepy but maybe adding it to the other class will help you. 
Otherwise, you should persist the category before trying to persist the book though I don't think you should have to do that.

Comment: After adding cascade type to Category side I got another exception: `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKAM8LLDERP40MVBBWCEQPU6L2S: PUBLIC.BOOK_CATEGORY FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CATEGORY(ID) (2)"; SQL statement:
insert into book_category (book_id, category_id) values (?, ?) [23506-196]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`

Comment: i see you have referenced columns in your table but the posted code doesnt have the annotation needed on the ids. change AT to the annotation (it thinks im trying to tag people)

In book you should 
    ATColumn(name = "book_id")
    ATId
    ATGeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

And in category

    ATColumn(name = "category_id")
    ATId
    ATGeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

Comment: You may want to rethink your relationship of books to categories. I'd imagine that you wouldn't want your books to dynamically generate categories... rather use categories that are prepopulated...

Comment: Well adding the @Column annotations solved InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException problem. But something is still not right with mapping collections. I edited my post and add stack trace of new exceptions I recived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution 1 : remove `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Possible solution 2 : add `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` in `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45781533/6572971

Comment: I tried both solutions but none of them works for me.