# Spring Data: managing a bidirectional many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have a bidirectional many-to-many relationship between a `Role` and `Scope`. Creating both entities and even their childs with the help of `CascadeType.PERSIST` is easy and straightforward.

The `Role` entity is simples as that:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "role_name", columnNames = "name"))
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Scope> scopes;

}
```

And the `Scope`:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "scope_name", columnNames = "name"))
public class Scope {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @JoinTable(name = "role_scopes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "scope_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

Their repositories are simply `CrudRepository` extensions:

```
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long> {}
public interface ScopeRepository extends CrudRepository<Scope, Long> {}
```

The following snippet exemplifies the entities insertion:

```
Role adminRole = roleRepository.save(new Role("ADMIN"));
Scope allReadScope = scopeRepository.save(new Scope("all.read"));
Scope allWriteScope = scopeRepository.save(new Scope("all.write"));
```

`Role` and `Scope` can be both automatically easily persisted with the help of the `CascadeType.PERSIST`, as follows:

```
Role managedRole = roleRepository.save(new Role("ADMIN", new Scope("all.read"), new Scope("all.write")));
```

However... Updating `managedRole` leads to `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist` exception:

```
managedRole.getScopes().remove(allReadScope);
roleRepository.save(managedRole); // PersistentObjectException!
```

I tried modifying the `Role::scopes`'s `CascadeType` to also include `DETACH`, `MERGE` and/or `REFRESH` with no success. How do we get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645091/spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-on-manytomany-re

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: Excuse me, Jens, but what for? Stacktrace shows a bunch of pointless function calls. The problem resides on the latest function call which leads to the exception above.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you face the problem, because you don't maintain both sides of the relationship in the bidirectional mapping. Lets say in `Role`:

```java
void add(Scope scope) {
   this.scopes.add(scope);
   scope.getRoles().add(this);
}
```

To be honest with you, I'd resign fully from bidirectional mapping. Maintaining this is a real nightmare.

Comment: It is actually maintained, I've just omitted it for brevity. I know it's a pain, but there's the only way I found to automatically create deletion cascade (upon `scope` deletion, also delete `role_scopes` if there's one).

Comment: Be careful with CascadeType.REMOVE in many-to-many -- by using it for ```scope``` you'll delete as you said ```scope```, ```role_scopes``` AND ```role```.