# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spatial

I Have two models, One is used to store user details and with that Id, I'm trying to save the user location in another table, which uses the same id of the user as the primary key.

**User Model**

```
public class User {
   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String Role;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private UserLocation location;
    
     //...constructors, getters and setters
 
}
```

**UserLocation Model**

```
@Entity
public class UserLocation {
   
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    @MapsId
    private User user;
    
    private Point location;
    //...constructors, getters and setters
}
```

My Spring Boot Application class where I try to insert records to both the table

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ContainmentZoneAlertApp implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private UserlocationRepository userLocRepo;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ContainmentZoneAlertApp.class, args);
                
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
        UserLocation userLocation = new UserLocation();
        Geometry geometry = GeometryUtil.wktToGeometry(String.format("POINT (13.0827 80.2707)"));
        //GeometryUtil is a utility class 

        User user = new User(null,"user 3","user3@gmail.com","hello123","user");
        user = userRepo.save(user);
        userLocation.setUser(user);
        userLocation.setLocation((Point)geometry);
        userLocRepo.save(userLocation);
    }

}
```

Im getting

```
caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.saravanan.models.User
```

Why am I getting this error? and what does persist mean? & I'm using MySQL database

Comment: Try putting @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) on UserLocation pojo's id field

Comment: or does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645091/spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-on-manytomany-re this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that both save operations are in the same transaction otherwise the first entity is detached an this leads to this exception.

So simply add `@Transactional` to the run method:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. But I want to save the user first and later save the user location, which means I don't save them at the same time. Will it be a problem? Can't I do that? What does "entity is detached" actually mean and why it is a problem? Thanks again

Comment: Sure you can do that. Make sure that read and save are in the same transaction. Read more about JPA states here https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-first-level-cache/